# How to map the collation in sqlserver to C# CultureInfo object? what should be the parameter for CultureInfo class?

Tags: c#, sql-server, collation, cultureinfo

Am trying create a **CultureInfo** object in my C# application based on the collation details retrieved from SqlServer.
When I query the database, collation details I receive is **Latin1_General_CI_AI**. How to use this info to create the cultureInfo object? Is there any other way to create cultureInfo object which matched the collation of SqlServer database?

Please provide your response.

Answer (score 2):

You do not. THere is no general mapping - especially as the SQL Server collations do combine code pages (not represented in C# CultureInfo) as well as implementation details (CL_AI actually are flags that indicate special behavior). There is no direct mapping also as a culture info contains additional information under the granularity of a collation which does not bother with elements like how numbers are to be formatted.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have a follow-up question, "SP_HELPLANGUAGE" query will list 'langid' with mapped lcid values, but it is not listing all the language which can support by SqlServer.  Could you please provide some information on how to create the culture info object ?

Comment: Well, I did say it is not possible. Which part of that was not understandable?

Comment: Hi TomTom, I found th querty to get the LCID value for the given collation name. Actually it is built-in function "COLLATIONPROPERTY". For more details refer to this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190305.aspx

Comment: @Srilaxmi Matching collation and culture through their respective LCID values will only get you so far. There is no guarantee that the retrieved `CultureInfo` instance will behave the same way the collation does. You can see for yourself: Latin1_General_CI_AI and Latin1_General_CS_AS will compare strings in a very different way, yet they both have an LCID property of 1033.

Answer (score 0):

This is query to get the LCID of the column in the table - "SELECT COLLATIONPROPERTY('COLLATIONPROPERTY', 'LCID') as 'LCID'" where as COLLAtIONPROPERTY is the collation name of the particular column.