# Why is there a difference in sorting between SQL Server and C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sorting

I am creating a table below

```
CREATE TABLE _testseif
(
    name NVARCHAR(max)
)

INSERT INTO _testseif (name)
VALUES (N'آ'), (N'ا')
```

When I sort these values:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo._testseif
ORDER BY name
```

I get these results:

[image: result in sql]

Now in C#, I wrote a unit test as shown here:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var li = new List<string>() { "آ" ,"ا" };

    var li1 = li.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
}
```

And the result I get is this:

[Result in c#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgznI.jpg)

Why is there a difference in sorting between SQL Server and C#?

Comment: SQL Server uses collations and C# uses CultureInfo, both based on the system in question, to sort strings. These generally do not match. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169514/how-to-map-the-collation-in-sqlserver-to-c-sharp-cultureinfo-object-what-should

Comment: Which collation are you using?

Comment: Hi @JonathanWillcock. sql server use `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CI_AS`

Comment: Very odd - when I switch to that collation I get the same order as c# ie. starts with I

Comment: @JonathanWillcock: Probably you are using a different CultureInfo than the questioner. So @A.R.SEIF: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: @Oliver No what I found odd was that my order with the same collation as OP is different to his order (just within SQL Server)

Comment: @Oliver CurrentCulture in c# is `en-US`

Comment: @A.R.SEIF The `SQL_` collations are sort-of-legacy collations that don't match Windows collation. You need `Latin1_General_CI_AS`. Beyond that, you're trying to use an en-US collation to sort arabic characters. And using the unnecessary `CP1256` codepage on a Unicode field. To get correct sorting use one of the `Arabic_` collations

Comment: Looking in Wiktionary it seems the two characters are the same character with a different accent. `آ` comes before `ا` in the Unicode table. So SQL Server works correctly. In C#, ordering a *character* array works the same. It's sorting strings that returns a different order, even for `ar`. You'll have to use `StringComparer.Ordinal` to get sorting by Unicode value